# R : How evaluate formals (arguments) of function?

Tags: r, functional-programming, arguments, lazy-evaluation

I really looked all over the place and haven't found an answer to my question :

**The Generalized Problem :**

- How do you evaluate arguments (`formals()`) of a R function, without launching it ?
- How do you evaluate a whole environment in R, despite the "Lazy evaluation" of R ?

**My problem :**

I want to get the computation time of the arguments of ANY function in R. For example, let's consider a function :

```
foo <- function(x, arg1 = 2, arg2 = arg3[1], arg3 = rnorm(10^6)) {
  rnorm(10^7) # whatever time-consuming computation here
  arg3^2
  message("Too bad you had to launch the whole function !")
}
```

You will note the difficulties :

- Some arguments are required (`x`), and some not. [Consequence : using `formals()` will not return the unevaluated expression of x !]
- Some arguments are computed in function of another, defined after it (`arg2` is computed with `arg3`)

**The desired output :**

```
> system.time(foo(x=1))
Too bad you had to launch the whole function !
       user      system      elapsed 
      1.835       0.000       1.573 

> solution.function(foo, list(x=1))
The answer is in reality much lower ! It takes only 0.2 sec to compute the arguments !
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Generalized solution

Very simply, it seems that `as.list(environment)` actually evaluates the whole environment and returns a list !

## My final solution

Thanks to the help of Martin Morgan, I came up with that solution, very simple, and which deals with all the constraints of the problem :

```
foo2 <- foo #Just copy/paste the function, before modifying it
body(foo2) <- quote(as.list(environment())
```

`foo2(x=2)` will return all the arguments of the function (evaluated), the required ones (`x`) as well as the default ones (`arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3`)

You can check : `system.time(foo2(x=1))` will return `0.2 seconds` ... only `rnorm(10^6)` is launched.

Answer (score 5):

Basically a hack, but make a copy of your function

```
g = foo
```

Replace the body of the function with an expression to evaluate each argument, being careful to allow errors to continue

```
body(g) = quote(lapply(formals(), function(x) try(eval(x), TRUE))
```

or maybe

```
body(g) = quote(sapply(formals(), function(x) system.time(try(eval(x), TRUE))))
```

Evaluate `g()` (the first version)

```
> g()
$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] 16

$c
[1] 16

$d
[1] 4

$e
[1] "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'unknown_variable' not found\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'unknown_variable' not found>
```

R has lazy evaluation, so this isn't a good method to measure the time inside versus outside the function. For instance, `f = function(y=Sys.sleep(Inf)) 1` returns immediately rather than never.

One would have to handle `...` arguments separately.

Comment: Your solution is much better than mine. Thank you !

Comment: Actually I just realized that this doesn't work when the function got a required arguments. I uploaded a very close solution that work in this case too.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I do have a vector named 'c' and a dataframe named 'd' in my workspace, so I get this from:

```
lapply( formals(foo), eval)
#---------
$a
[1] 2

$b
function (..., recursive = FALSE)  .Primitive("c")

$c
      a  b a2 b2
[1,]  1 NA  1 NA
[2,]  4 NA  4 NA
[3,]  9 NA  9 NA
[4,] 16 NA 16 NA
[5,] 25 NA 25 NA

$d
[1] 4

Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors
```

It's not exactly what is returned from your `EvalFormals`, but it seems to be what I (a reasonably seasoned R user) would have expected. I fail to appreciate the possible connection with measuring execution times.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answers above, in case anyone also then wants those variables in their global environment (e.g. for troubleshooting the function).

```
Troubleshoot_function = function(fn, ...)
{
  body(fn) = quote(expr = lapply(formals(), 
                                 FUN = function(x)
                                   {
                                   try(eval(x), TRUE)
                                   }
                                 )
                  )
  ex = fn(...)
  nm = names(ex)
  invisible(
    {
  lapply(X = 1:length(ex),
         FUN = function(i)
                 {
                 assign(x = nm[i],
                        value = ex[[i]],
                        envir = .GlobalEnv,
                        pos = -1
                        )
                 }
         )
    }
  )
}

#example
Troubleshoot_function(foo)
 ls()
[1] "arg1"                  "arg2"                  "arg3"                 
[4] "foo"                   "Troubleshoot_function" "x"      
arg1
[1] 2
```